# Get Current Operating System In Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I'm making an App using Adobe Flex/Air. I was wondering if there is any way to get the Operating System the Air app is running on?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [Capabilities](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/system/Capabilities.html#os) class:

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;

trace(Capabilities.os);
```

Comment: This is available in flash too :) not just in AIR :)

Comment: but how can we identify Solaris OS

Answer (score 12):

```
if((Capabilities.os.indexOf("Windows") >= 0))
{
     // in windows
}
else if((Capabilities.os.indexOf("Mac") >= 0))
{
// in mac
 } 
 else if((Capabilities.os.indexOf("Linux") >= 0))
 {
// in linux
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

For clarity sake, I use this code (although it does the same thing as Mudasir's)

```
if(Capabilities.os.search("Windows")>=0)
     //do something
```

Here are what the docs say:

flash.system.Capabilities.os():String
[Read Only] Specifies the current operating system. The os property can return the following strings: Operating system Value

Windows 7
Windows Vista
Windows Server 2008 R2
Windows Server 2008
Windows Home Server
Windows Server 2003 R2
Windows Server 2003
Windows Server XP 64
Windows XP
Windows 98
Windows 95
Windows NT
Windows 2000
Windows ME
Windows CE
Windows SmartPhone
Windows PocketPC
Windows CEPC
Windows Mobile
Mac OS "Mac OS X.Y.Z" (where X.Y.Z is the version number, for example: "Mac OS 10.5.2")
 
Linux "Linux" (Flash Player attaches the Linux version, such as "Linux 2.6.15-1.2054_FC5smp" 
iPhone OS 4.1 "iPhone3,1"

The server string is OS.

Do not use Capabilities.os to determine a capability based on the operating system if a more specific capability property exists. Basing a capability on the operating system is a bad idea, since it can lead to problems if an application does not consider all potential target operating systems. Instead, use the property corresponding to the capability for which you are testing. For more information, see the Capabilities class description.

Language Version:
3.0
Player Version:
Flash 9, AIR 1.0, Lite 4

Comment: how can we identify Solaris OS